# Why is this DIV padded at the top?

Tags: html, css

Here is a test-case for my problem:

http://game-point.net/misc/testParaPadding/

I want the `progressBarGreen.png` image to be inside the DIV, and the DIV is exactly the right height (15px) to hold it, but there are a couple of pixels padding at the top of the DIV.  Why?  The browser seems to be sizing the content as if it contained text because the padding changes if I remove the `font-family` styling for the body, but there is no text in the DIV.

Interestingly this problem doesn't happen in Firefox's quirks mode.

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4Vyxe/)

Comment: Always helpful to have a working example in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Trouble is that example's image will break if I delete it from my server. ;-)

Comment: True, but I made a safe assumption that you'd have that example working until you've got your answer?

Comment: Yep but maybe not long term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `line-height:15px` on the `div` holding the image

*edit:* Explanation for this behaviour [line-height affecting even no-text blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133024/line-height-affecting-even-no-text-blocks)

Comment: OK, but why is the browser treating the image as if it were text?  You're basically saying the browser should be told about text's line height, but the DIV doesn't contain any text.

Comment: HTML dude, don't ask why :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133024/line-height-affecting-even-no-text-blocks

Comment: Ah, that question pretty much answers it.  Thanks.

Comment: i dont think this works, it still displayed same. Hence i updated my answer by adding a position for the image. check if i am correct!

Answer (score 2):

Your image is the right size, but images are inline elements by default, and will be affected by the page's `line-height`, `font-size`, and other properties of inline elements.

If you add a line to your image's style reading `display: block;`, it will become a block-level element, and not be affected by any of those properties.

Comment: This is the solution I chose.  It seems bizarre to me that they chose to make even non-text elements be affected by things like font-size.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

The [initial value](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align) for `vertical-align` is always "baseline".
You can fix that by adding a `vertical-align:top` to your image ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
position:absolute;
```

To get the image on the other DIV exactly inside it.

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sRhXc/2/

Comment: This is a horrible workaround. `position:fixed` will make the image positioned relative to the window, not the document. See this http://jsfiddle.net/sRhXc/1/ (scroll down)

Comment: Sorry, i just thought that only that particular status bar will be displayed in that page. if this is the case we can use `position:absolute` check this [link] http://jsfiddle.net/sRhXc/2/

Comment: `position:absolute;` is a better workaround. (I'd recommend making **that** your answer, as opposed to `position:fixed;`) I say this because if you had other elements to put in the status bar (such as text to indicate completion, like "50% complete"), `position:absolute;` would not affect its positioning relative to the left side, regardless of how wide the image becomes.

Comment: @Nightfirecat Thanks. I changed the answer to absolute